# ADB não reconhece dispositivo Android no Mac OS

Tags: android, osx, android-eclipse

Estou tentando ativar o modo de *debugger* no meu Motorola Razr i pra poder rodar meus projetos Android no próprio dispositivo.

Mas quando eu entro no terminal do Mac e coloco o comando `./adb devices` para listar os dispositivos que estão conectados, não aparece nada.

Fiz um teste, deixei o meu celular conectado no Mac e abri o emulador do eclipse. Rodei novamente o terminal, entrei no ADB e visualizou apenas o emulador.

O que pode estar acontecendo para que o Mac não reconheça meu celular, ou o que eu estou esquecendo de fazer ou fazendo errado?

Comment: A **Depuração USB** nas opções de desenvolvimento do seu aparelho já está ativada?

Comment: Existe um arquivo: .android/adb_usb.ini, talvez precise adicionar o vendor id da USB nessa lista

Answer (score 4):

Fica um pouco difícil "adivinhar" os fatores com que estamos lidando nesta situação, mas vou tentar ajudar com o pouco de experiência que tive com o ADB + Mac OS. A seguir, algumas perguntas que podem ajudar a diagnosticar o problema; editarei a resposta de acordo com futuras informações:

## Checklist da Situação

(1) Qual versão do **Mac OS** você está usando? 10.6 (**Snow Leopard**), 10.7 (**Lion**), 10.8 (**ML**), 10.9 (**Mavericks**) ou 10.10 (**Yosemite**)? Ou nenhuma delas? (Talvez uma mais antiga.)
(2) Você mencionou *Eclipse* - acredito que tenha baixado o *Android SDK* mais recente e tenha acesso a todas as ferramentas?
(3) Quando diz que *"...estou tentando ativar o modo debugger..."*, você está afirmando que já desbloqueou o **Modo Desenvolvedor** tocando rapidamente (7-8 vezes ) no **Build Number** em *"Configurações > Sobre o celular"*? (Assumindo as versões mais recentes do Android, pode variar de acordo com fabricante e versão.).
(4) Que versão do OS você tem em seu celular? 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4? É *stock* ou você carregou uma *custom ROM*? Se for *stock*, você tomou acesso **root**?
(5) Se tratarmos de uma *custom ROM*, você tem certeza de que ele está funcionando *como deveria*? Já tive casos em que, "zoei" tanto o aparelho, que tive de fazer um *factory reset* para voltar a *debuggar* como deveria.
(6) Uma vez verificadas todas as etapas acima, você chegou a testar em uma outra máquina, de preferência com outro sistema operacional (com seus devidos drivers instalados.) como Linux ou **Windows**? O Mac OS não precisa de drivers para rodar o ADB na maioria dos Androids (pelo menos não nos que testei - Samsungs Galaxy S2-S4, Moto E/G/X)

## Um pouco de "*Troubleshooting*"

Agora, vamos tentar tratar o problema.

#### ADB e Privilégios

O `adb-server` é iniciado logo na primeira vez em que você executa o comando `./adb devices`, pois ele precisa de uma interface de comunicação (e.g. "*daemon*") para se ouvir em uma porta aleatória e estabelecer comunicação com o OS no celular. Esse *daemon* precisa de privilégios para gravar via USB e, por se tratar de um sistema baseado em *UNIX*, talvez o seu problema possa ser o de estar executando o `adb` de um local/usuário sem privilégios para tanto. Experimente executar  `sudo ./adb devices` para eliminar a hipótese de ser um problema gerado por falta de privilégios. - Se o *daemon* já estiver sendo executado, antes de mais nada, **mate** o processo com um `kill [PID]`onde `[PID]` é o identificador do processo. Você pode descobrir isso com algo simples como `ps aux | grep adb`. (Se, por algum acaso, o processo travar e não "morrer", tente `kill -9 [PID]`.

#### Hardware > Software > Troca de Ambiente

Outra possível falha nessa comunicação pode ser, irônicamente, o cabo. Teste com outro cabo USB para ter certeza de que este não é o problema. Ou ainda, nessa mesma linha, tente montar o compartilhamento USB no seu dispostivo e transferir algum arquivo via [*Android File Transfer*](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/), um cliente desenvolvido justamente pra isso - transferir arquivos de Android para Mac. Se você conseguir fazer essa transferência, então seu cabo e a comunicação estão **OK**.

Se sua verificação de hardware não apresentar problemas e não existirem motivos óbvios para o software não "conversar" devidamente, experimente o passo **(6)** do checklist. Experimente em outro sistema e veja se tudo funciona bem. Você pode usar algo como [15 sec. ADB Installer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979) para preparar uma máquina com Windows em questão de segundos para realizar seu teste. Sem ter de baixar o SDK todo novamente.

Se o *Android File Transfer*, como mencionado acima, funcionar normalmente mas o `adb` continuar não enxergando seu dispositivo, você tem um de dois problemas:
(1) Seu celular não está conseguindo emular a depuração USB
(2) Suas bibliotecas/kexts no OS X de alguma forma estão bagunçadas

De qualquer forma, só será possível ajudar além disso, com mais informações. Espero poder ter ajudado de alguma forma.